# Weird Reselect selector behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, reselect

For some reason, my `selector` function only gets called when one of the arguments change but not the other.

Here is my `selector` that gets `transactions` from `state` and applies 2 filters to them

```
export const getFilteredTransactionsSelector = createSelector(
  (state) => state.transactions.transactions,
  (items) =>
    memoize((filterValueFirst, filterValueSecond) =>
      items
        .filter((item) => {
          if (filterValueFirst === "Show All") {
            return true;
          }
          return item["Status"] === filterValueFirst;
        })
        .filter((item) => {
          if (filterValueSecond === "Show All") {
            return true;
          }
          return item["Type"] === filterValueSecond;
        })
    )
);
```

In my component's `mapStateToProps` I pass current state to the `selector`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  transactions: getTransactions(state),
  getFilteredTransactions: getFilteredTransactionsSelector(state),
  ...
});
```

And then I call it whenever one of the filter values changes

```
useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredTransactions(
      getFilteredTransactions(statusFilterValue, typeFilterValue)
    );
  }, [transactions, statusFilterValue, typeFilterValue]);
```

The problem is that I get filtered data only when I change the first filter's value (`statusFilterValue`). If I change the 2nd one, nothing happens despite the fact that the `useEffect` hook gets called as it should be. 
If I put `console.log` inside `memoize` function, it will only show the result if I change the first filter but not the second. Any help would be appreaciated

Comment: solved the problem by passing ```filterValues``` as an ```Object``` and destructuring it in ```memoize``` function. Still not sure why it behaved the way it did

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in `memoize` you didn't say where it came from. Reselect exports [defaultMemoize](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/blob/master/src/index.js#L21). If the effect runs when you change only typeFilterValue then you didn't mutate it but it looks like you are mutating it and the effect runs because other dependencies changed (maybe transactions).

Comment: Sorry ```memoize``` comes from ```lodash``` lib and that's the way they suggest in docs 
https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#q-how-do-i-create-a-selector-that-takes-an-argument

By the way, the ```useEffect``` hook responds to changes in both filters, so it should be calling the function no matter what. But if I put ```console.log()``` inside ```memoize``` function it won't be invoked if I changed the 2nd filter. This is what I find weird. Anyway, I think I will stick to passing both values as an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from the code in your question you don't need memoize at all. If you did need it then better use the one that is already in reselect and prevent adding unnecessary dependencies.

You also don't need an effect since what selectFilteredTransactions returns will not change as long as items, filterValueFirst or filterValueSecond won't change and if setFilteredTransactions comes from useState then passing the same value to it between renders won't cause any re render.

You can create the selector like so:

```
export const selectFilteredTransactions = createSelector(
  (state) => state.transactions.transactions,
  (a, filterValueFirst) => filterValueFirst,
  (a, b, filterValueSecond) => filterValueSecond,
  (items, filterValueFirst, filterValueSecond) =>
    console.log('running selector, something changed') ||
    items
      .filter((item) => {
        if (filterValueFirst === 'Show All') {
          return true;
        }
        return item['Status'] === filterValueFirst;
      })
      .filter((item) => {
        if (filterValueSecond === 'Show All') {
          return true;
        }
        return item['Type'] === filterValueSecond;
      })
);
```

And call it like this:

```
//don't even need the effect here since filteredTransactions
//  only changes when items, filterValueFirst or filterValueSecond
//  changes
setFilteredTransactions(//assuming this comes from useState
  useSelector((state) =>
    selectFilteredTransactions(
      state,
      statusFilterValue,
      typeFilterValue
    )
  )
);
```